# Can AWS EventBridge call a private endpoint in ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge

Is it possible to call a private subnet API hosted in ECS from the event bridge?.

I tried calling using an internal load balancer it didn't work.

Comment: Call how exactly? What would be the target of EB rule?

Comment: @Marcin I have configured my internal load balancer endpoint as an API destination
and configured that API destination as a target of my EB